# Sample size calculation in two different population for administration of a questionnaire

Tags: sampling, sample-size, survey, sample, group-differences

I need some help calculating a sample size.
I have two groups of people to whom I need to fill out a questionnaire. Group A consists of 45,000 people and group B consists of 3,000 people.
How do I know what is the right sample size for group A and group B?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hello Egn! It's quite impossible to say without knowing what you want to measure or compare, you need to provide much more information than that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is a questionnaire on the use of a drug to be submitted to Italian and Albanian doctors. The Italian doctors total 45,000 while the doctors in Albania total 3000. Now I wonder, how many Italian doctors should I submit the questionnaire to and how many to Albanian doctors? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to compare if they answer differently to a yes/no question, the calculation for the required sample size may be different than if you need to compare, let's say, how many times they prescribe the drug during a given year. In short, we need more information about the variables you want to analyze - e.g. if they are categorical (if so, how many levels?), ordinal, continuous, etc., and the kind of statistical test you plan to use.

Comment: By the way, if you want you can edit your post to make all these information more visible, rather than giving them in the comment section.

Comment: Also, I assumed that you want to compare Italian to Albanian doctors, but if comparison is not your goal, you should mention what you are looking for.

Comment: OK, I'll try to be more specific. The questionnaire has four sections. The first section concerns age, gender, nationality, etc., so general aspects. The other sections are questions that the doctor has to answer yes or no (so dicotomous as you were saying).But some questions can have three choices such as: 

With which protocol do you administer the drug?
a) 3 times a day for 6 days
b) 6 times a day for 3 days
c)1 time a day for 10 days

Thank you very much for your quick and complete answers, I hope I was more precise

Comment: I'm going to be quite busy these days and in the coming weeks, and won't have the time to answer your question, which may be quite involved. However, you should edit your original question to add all these information you gave in comments. It will make the information much more visible to possible respondents. In addition, editing your question will move your question up in the list of top questions (so more people will see it).